# Polymodel on App Engine suggestion

Tags: google-app-engine, model, google-cloud-datastore

I'm designing a model for a posting system where an entry contains an image with or without a comment. An user can reply to it as either a comment or as an image entry as well.

As there can be more properties for ImageEntry, I came up with this design with Polymodel. Not sure if this is the best way to do this. Storage-wise, is CommentEntry less than ImageEntry?

Any suggestions would be great.

```
class Entry(polymodel.PolyModel):
  comment    = db.TextProperty()
  reply_to   = db.SelfReferenceProperty() # reference to the entry
  created_at = properties.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = properties.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

class CommentEntry(Entry):
  created_by = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='comment_entries')

class ImageEntry(Entry):
  created_by = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='image_entries')
  image_url  = db.LinkProperty(indexed=False)
  slug       = db.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this model will work fine, and yes, a CommentEntry will be smaller than an ImageEntry from the same user if the ImageEntry has an image URL and/or slug.

however, i'd make this much simpler by putting
created_by, image_url, and slug into Entry and getting rid
of CommentEntry and ImageEntry altogether. since
[the app engine datastore is schemaless](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Introducing_the_Python_Datastore),
and [properties are optional by default](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property),
you'll only pay the cost of the image_url and slug properties when you fill them
in for image entries.

Comment: I actually have several more properties for ImageEntry, but it's definitely simpler to just have Entry. Thanks for clearing that up.